# Failed to create shortcut for sublime in ubuntu terminal

Tags: shortcuts

I am trying to create a shortcut for sublime.

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/sublime sublime
```

But an error comes upon entering the code above.

```
 ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/sublime': File exists
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a destination directory for your file. Since you didn't specify what directory you are in when issuing the ln command I'm assuming you are in /usr/bin/.  If that is the case then you are trying to create a link with the same name as an existing file. Try

`ln -s /usr/bin/sublime ~/sublime`